# Virus total API

Tags: python, api

I want to use API for "Virustotal" to scan the files, I have tried the APIs given the "https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/" but none of them worked for me. One of the examples is given below,

In Virus Totals API in ASP + Python file I got the error. There are two files namely Filescan.py and postfile.py. While ruuning Filescan.py.

The file Filescan contains,

```
import sys
import postfile
host = "www.virustotal.com"
selector = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan"
fields = [("apikey", "api key")]
file_to_send = open("my file", "rb").read()
files = [("file","my file",file_to_send)]
json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)
`enter code here`print (json)
```

And the postfile.py consist of

```
import http.client, mimetypes
def post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files):
    content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)
    h = http.client.HTTPS(host)
    h.putrequest('POST', selector)
    h.putheader('content-type', content_type)
    h.putheader('content-length', str(len(body)))
    h.endheaders()
    h.send(body)
    errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
    return h.file.read()
def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):
    BOUNDARY = '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$'
    CRLF = '\r\n'
    L = []
    for (key, value) in fields:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    for (key, filename, value) in files:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (key, filename))
        L.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename))
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
    L.append('')
    body = CRLF.join(str(L))
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
    return content_type, body
def get_content_type(filename):
    return mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
```

While I run the Filescan.py it gives the error like "AttributeError: module 'http.client' has no attribute 'HTTPS'"
How to solve this?
Does anybody know the working API for Virustotal in windows?

Comment: The HTTP posting code is verbose and complex. I suggest using Request library which makes writing HTTP clients much much more simpler http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Also the question lacks full error traceback

Answer (score 0):

**install virus_total_apis module, check : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virustotal-api/**

Url Scanner sample:

```
import virus_total_apis, json


def online_scan(api_key, target_url):

    switch_api_key = virus_total_apis.PublicApi(api_key)

    response = switch_api_key.get_url_report(target_url)
    raw_data_json = json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    raw_json_dict = json.loads(raw_data_json)

    return raw_json_dict

print(online_scan('your_api', 'www.google.com'))
```